# How to get value of id in Url from Razor View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a simple ASP.NET Core web application with a page like such `http://localhost:5050/Posts/Create/3`.

In my Razor View `Views/Posts/Create.cshtml`, how would I be able to get the value "3" so that I can create a link like `<a href="/Blogs/Details/3">« Back to Blog</a>`?

So far, created the link using the following Tag Helper, but I don't know what to put for `asp-route-id`:

```
<a asp-controller="Blogs" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="" class="btn btn-default btn pull-right">&laquo; Back</a>
```

I am just using the default mvc route:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I know I can get it from the Model (i.e., `Model.Blog.BlogId`), but I'm looking to get it from the Url using something like `Request.Query["id"]` in `Views/Post/Create.cshtml`.

I tried `asp-route-id="@Context.Request.Query["id"]`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like that `Context.GetRouteData().Values["id"];` ?

Also http://www.blakepell.com/how-to-get-the-current-route-in-a-view-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6

Comment: Yeah, that's not for asp.net core. There is no `RequestContext` in asp.net core.

Comment: First line is asp.net core, pasted from my project, but maybe not usable exactly as you wish. What about the last link? I haven't tried but it is supposed to be MVC 6.

Comment: Hey, I just tried `Context.GetRouteData().Values["id"]` and it works. Can you edit your answer? I will mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: You can also use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]`

Comment: I'm using Asp.net Core 2.0 and only @MarkG's solution worked for me

Answer (score 13):

Currently in ASP.NET Core 2.1 & 3.1 this works:

```
Context.Request.Query["id"]
```

Answer (score 7):

in ASP.NET Core 3.1 & .NET 5 & .NET 6 this works for me:

```
@Context.Request.RouteValues["id"]
```

Answer (score 5):

FWIW: I use @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["yourRouteId"]

Answer (score 4):

It looks like in Asp.Net Core 2.2 only the statement "@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]" will get the id from a link like this "https://localhost:44356/Administration/AddUser/0". 
If you have a url like this one "https://localhost:44356/Administration/AddUser/0?status=False" and you want to get the value of "status" you can use "@Context.Request.Query["status"]"

Answer (score 3):

use [FromRoute] to achieve the same .

@page "myaccount/{id}"

```
@function{
  [FromRoute]
  public string Id {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For aspcore 2.1, use:  `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query["id"]`

Answer (score 0):

This what I have used which is simple c# code works with .net core and pure MVC also:

```
 var reqUrl = Request.HttpContext.Request;
 var urlHost = reqUrl.Host;
 var urlPath = reqUrl.Path;
 var urlQueryString= reqUrl.QueryString;
 if (urlQueryString == null)
 {
 ViewBag.URL= urlHost + urlPath;
 }
 else
 {
 ViewBag.URL= urlHost + urlPath + urlQueryString;
 }
```